# R returns NA when I try to coerce a string to date using as.Date

Tags: r, date, locale

I am trying to convert `"March 15, 2017"` to date.
`as.Date("March 15, 2017", "%B %d, %Y")` and it returned NA
I feel that the syntax fits well, what is the problem?

Comment: If I copy the example in the documentation, it still don't work on my machine. Is there something wrong?

Comment: But if i run this in the documentation console, it worked...

Comment: It is really weird.

Comment: this seems to be a local issue, I cannot replicate it. what is your version of **R** and what OS are you using?

Comment: @DrorBogin it's a locale thing and indeed a "local" issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but have been bitten by your locale. If you look at the documentation for `strptime`, you will notice that

```
%B   Full month name in the current locale. (Also matches abbreviated name on input.)
```

This is also the case for my system since Slovenian doesn't have English month names:

```
> as.Date("March 15, 2017", "%B %d, %Y")
[1] NA

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250;LC_CTYPE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250;LC_MONETARY=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250"
```

What you can do is change locale, perhaps only for the duration of the conversion.

```
> Sys.setlocale(locale = "English")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
> as.Date("March 15, 2017", "%B %d, %Y")
[1] "2017-03-15"
```

And then back to normal

```
> Sys.setlocale(locale = "Slovenian")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250;LC_CTYPE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250;LC_MONETARY=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250"
> as.Date("March 15, 2017", "%B %d, %Y")
[1] NA
```

But if I use a Slovenian name for March:

```
> as.Date("Marec 15, 2017", "%B %d, %Y")
[1] "2017-03-15"
```

Locale name will depend on your operating system, see `?Sys.setlocale` for more info.

Comment: Perfect. That works! Thank you.